# Error on PM2 - type.slice is not a function

Tags: pm2

I'm using PM2 version 5.1.2 with the app in cluster mode. Getting this error and pm2 keeps restarting with the same error.

Seems like it has something to do with the cluster mode, but I couldn't find a solution.

```
PM2          | ===============================================================================
PM2          | --- PM2 global error caught ---------------------------------------------------
PM2          | Time                 : Tue Dec 21 2021 13:45:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
PM2          | type.slice is not a function
PM2          | TypeError: type.slice is not a function
PM2          |     at EventEmitter.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js:343:77)
PM2          |     at Worker.cluMessage (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ClusterMode.js:65:24)
PM2          |     at Worker.emit (events.js:412:35)
PM2          |     at Worker.emit (domain.js:537:15)
PM2          |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/worker.js:33:12)
PM2          |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
PM2          |     at ChildProcess.emit (domain.js:537:15)
PM2          |     at emit (internal/child_process.js:912:12)
PM2          |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
PM2          | ===============================================================================
PM2          | [PM2] Resurrecting PM2
```

PM2 config:

```
--- Daemon -------------------------------------------------
pm2d version         : 5.1.2
node version         : 14.18.2
node path            : /usr/bin/pm2
argv                 : /usr/bin/node,/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Daemon.js
argv0                : node
user                 : marcos
uid                  : 1001
gid                  : 1002
uptime               : 0min
===============================================================================
--- CLI ----------------------------------------------------
local pm2            : 5.1.2
node version         : 14.18.2
node path            : /usr/bin/pm2
argv                 : /usr/bin/node,/usr/bin/pm2,report
argv0                : node
user                 : marcos
uid                  : 1001
gid                  : 1002
===============================================================================
--- System info --------------------------------------------
arch                 : x64
platform             : linux
type                 : Linux
cpus                 : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
cpus nb              : 2
freemem              : 6384754688
totalmem             : 8340885504
home                 : /home/marcos
===============================================================================
```

Comment: share us your pm2 config, node version and os. If you are able to replicate it with a minimal project, we could test it locally

Comment: Added config. I will try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: @marcosspn Did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a package or package version mismatch between the one installed globally and the one installed locally. In my case, I had installed the [@socket.io/pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@socket.io/pm2) package globally but [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) was installed locally.